# Incoming block handler is never called when using bitcore

Tags: bitpay, bitcore

I want to get blocks on my node with [bitcore](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore).

For example, I'm using peermanager.js and I get transactions:

```
var handleTx = function(info) {
  var tx = info.message.tx.getStandardizedObject();
  console.log('** TX Received **');
  console.log(tx);
};
```

and it's printing transactions.

However, when I use this part:

```
var handleBlock = function(info) {
  console.log('** Block Received **');
  console.log(info.message);
};
```

It doesn't log anything to the console.

Comment: Can you post the code that registers these as handlers with your PeerManager?

Comment: Here is the module https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore

Comment: I don't believe this is printing transactions. What you are getting is a list of transactions that another peer has available. Also without your code it's impossible to tell how you are using ´handleTx´ and ´handleBlock´ objects.

Comment: I stoped to use this library now I use Insight API
https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api